# How to convert a block.timestamp to a date year/month/day/hour/minute using solidity?

Tags: date, timestamp, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to set up a voting system where, as soon as it starts, the user can see on what date the voting started. Demonstrating, voting started on 2022/10/07 at 18:40

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library to convert timestamp to datetime
https://github.com/RollaProject/solidity-datetime#timestamptodatetime

```
function timestampToDateTime(uint timestamp) public pure returns (uint year, uint month, uint day, uint hour, uint minute, uint second)
```